# Image button wont hide during page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a imagebutton on my grid view

```
  <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stop">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="StopImageButton" runat="server" OnClick="StopImageButton_Click"
                        ImageUrl="~/Stop.jpg" Width="25" Height="25" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
```

and I have this code on my page_load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton i = new ImageButton();
        i.ID = "StopImageButton";
        i.Visible = false;
    }
```

What I want to do is, Hide my 'stop button' on page load. But how can I do it? It still wont hide?

Comment: What is the name of your `stop button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reason is you are creating new image button on page load and set visible false in that new image button.

what you can do is, find the image button on the gridview and set visible false.

update `RowDataBound` event of your grid view as below.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton ImgBtn= e.Row.FindControl("StopImageButton") as ImageButton;
        if(ImgBtn !=null)
            ImgBtn.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **Damith** said, You are creating a new instance of button. So what you are doing is right to create a new button and hide it. But its wrong to hide an already created button.

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.StopImageButton.Visible = false;
}
```